# CSS to display a constant background to cover up

Tags: css, background

I want to know how to have the page content to roll over the background image as the user scrolls down the page. Below is a link to better understand what I'm talking about. I don't care about the video, maybe to do this with just an image. How would you do this using CSS3? Would you be able to do this using CSS2?

[Here is the link](http://twodoorcinemaclub.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

That property is in CSS2 and CSS3.  Define a background image, use `background-attachment: fixed`, and position your page content low enough that the background image is visible.